# How well will Ubuntu run on my Compaq Presario V2000 Laptop?

Tags: installation, ram

I have Compaq Presario V2000 Laptop that have 504Mb of ram but I'm not sure of it's requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run 12.04 for sure but 3d mode  can be slow or even unsupported..  at least you can use 2d mode and tweak it to make it better

- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/unity-2d-tweaking-tool-adds-minor-new-options

Comment: This look good but looks like I will not gonna enjoy unity with 3d after all :(

Comment: this depends on your graphic card cause amount of ram fits requirements so maybe it will work but there is nothing to special about it exept some effects.

Comment: If your system is sufficiently old enough, 3d won't work.  It'll run in 2d mode, though, automatically, if your system doesn't support 3d\.

Comment: Please include details from the link in order to answer the question. Should the link go down, this answer would not help future users.